# Matrix basis using `Orthogonalize`

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, vector

I have four matrices,

```
{a,b,c,d}={{{0.389959, -0.0172927 - 0.046773 I}, {-0.0172927 + 0.046773 I, 0.610041}}, 
           {{0.384355, 0.150761 - 0.110966 I}, {0.150761 + 0.110966 I,0.615645}}, 
           {{0.407367, -0.036374 - 0.206074 I}, {-0.036374 + 0.206074 I,0.592633}}, 
           {{0.28957, -0.0466929 - 0.449934 I}, {-0.0466929 + 0.449934 I, 0.71043}}}
```

The inner product is defined as

```
ip[x_,y_]:=Tr[ConjugateTranspose[x] y]
```

I tried to find a basis using `Orthogonalize`

```
Orthogonalize[{a,b,c,d},ip]
```

But I got,

```
{{{0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}}, 
 {{0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}}, 
 {{0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}}, 
 {{0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}}}
```

as the output.

Where did I go wrong? Can't we use `Orthogonalize` for matrices? If not, how to find a matrix basis in Mathematica?

EDIT

I replaced all the entries with integers,

```
 Orthogonalize[{{{1, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {6, 5}}, 
               {{4, 4}, {4,6}}, {{3, 4 }, {5, 7}}}, ip]
```

yielding an output,

```
 {{{1/Sqrt[26], 2 Sqrt[2/13]}, {Sqrt[2/13], 5/Sqrt[26]}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {0,  0}}, 
 {{5/Sqrt[26], -(55/(7 Sqrt[26]))}, 
  {(9 Sqrt[2/13])/ 7, -(1/Sqrt[26])}}, 
 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
```

Issue due to complex numbers?

EDIT

So I made a mistake. The inner product should be,

```
  ip[x_,y_]:=Tr[ConjugateTranspose[x] . y]
```

But this still doesn't give the basis. The issue is with the complex part of the inner product defined. Even though its zero, Mathematica still identifies it as a complex number. Redefining `ip` as,

```
 ip[x_,y_]:=Re[Tr[ConjugateTranspose[x] . y]]
```

yields the solution.

Comment: Just checking: did you mean to use the Hadamard product (`Times[]`) instead of the dot product (`Dot[]`) in your definition for `ip[]`?

Comment: Check if your matrices are not linearly dependent.

Comment: @DanielHuber Even if they are, the basis should contain at least one non-zero matrix right?

Comment: @J.M. No, I meant to use the Dot product

Comment: This is correct. Maybe you should report it to: support@wolfram.com

Comment: Since `ip[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]` produces `0`, your `ip` is not any inner product (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) for info).

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `ip` as,

```
  ip[x_,y_]:=Re[Tr[ConjugateTranspose[x] . y]]
```

Comment: In the above definition `Re` is  not necessary because `ip[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}]` results in `Re[a Conjugate[a] + b Conjugate[b] + c Conjugate[c] + d Conjugate[d]]`. In fact, this is a variation of Frobenius inner product.